# Orderby entry field?

Tags: entries, entries-field, sort

I am getting music album entries with the following code:

```
   {% set entries = craft.entries()
      .section('releases')
      .orderBy('title ASC')
      .all() %}
```

Rather than ordering by the title, I would like to order by the title of the artist.

The artist is a entry field which I render with:

```
entry.artist.one().title
```

How can I order these entries by artist?

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:

1. [How to order by related entry type field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14288/how-to-order-by-related-entry-type-field)
2. https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6010

If you use the logic of the 1st variant, then it should come out something like this:

```
{# Get all aritsts sorted by title #}
{% for artists in arists %}
    {# Get releases only related to looped artist #}
    {% set releases = craft.entries.section('releases').relatedTo(arist) %}
    {% for release in releases %}
        {# Do whatever you want here, it should be sorted #}
        <p>Artist name: {{ artist.title }}</p>
        <p>Release name: {{ release.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```